# cpp - make with lboost_system - how to make it work

Tags: c++

In my cpp project, I have header file with `#include <boost/asio.hpp>`.

i also got a makefile attached to the project:

```
   CFLAGS:=-c -Wall -Weffc++ -g -std=c++11 -Iinclude
LDFLAGS:=-L/Users/user/Downloads/boost_1_61_0

all: EchoClient
    g++ -o bin/echoExample bin/connectionHandler.o bin/echoClient.o $(LDFLAGS) 

EchoClient: bin/connectionHandler.o bin/echoClient.o

bin/connectionHandler.o: src/connectionHandler.cpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -o bin/connectionHandler.o src/connectionHandler.cpp

bin/echoClient.o: src/echoClient.cpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -o bin/echoClient.o src/echoClient.cpp

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f bin/*
```

What I need to to in order to make the program compile and run?
Do i need to download boost and put it in some folder? 
Do i need to change the value `LDFLAGS` that inside the makefile to the download boost destination?

This is what i did so far, but it seems wrong because when I run `make` I get this error:

```
g++ -o bin/echoExample bin/connectionHandler.o bin/echoClient.o -L/Users/user/Downloads/boost_1_61_0 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::system::system_category()", referenced from:
      boost::asio::error::get_system_category() in connectionHandler.o
      boost::system::error_code::error_code() in connectionHandler.o
      ___cxx_global_var_init.2 in connectionHandler.o
      boost::asio::error::get_system_category() in echoClient.o
      ___cxx_global_var_init.2 in echoClient.o
  "boost::system::generic_category()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in connectionHandler.o
      ___cxx_global_var_init.1 in connectionHandler.o
      ___cxx_global_var_init in echoClient.o
      ___cxx_global_var_init.1 in echoClient.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [all] Error 1
Am i doing it OK?
```

I'm tring to run it both in mac and in windows
The folder boost_1_61_0 contains folders: boosts, libs, status, more, tools and more

Comment: The Makefile you pasted does not correspond with the output you get: where did `-lboost_system` in `LDFLAGS` go to?

Comment: sorrt, edited, thanks

Comment: The `-L` flag tells the linker *where* to look. You need to add `-lboost_system` so it knows *what* to look for. `LDFLAGS:=-L/Users/user/Downloads/boost_1_61_0 -lboost_system`

Comment: thanks, i now get error: `ld: library not found for -lboost_system`. the folder `boost_1_61_0` contains folders: boosts, libs, status, more, tools and more. This is the path i need?

Comment: No, the `-L` flag needs to point to the directory that contains `libboost_system-...dylib`. It _may_ be in the `libs` subdirectory, I don't know.

Comment: it should be inside the boost_1_61_0 folder? It doesn't there..

Comment: Did you download the boost _source_ distribution? You need to actually build and install it. You should install boost with `brew` or `macports` instead, then `libboost_system-...dylib` will just accessible as a system library.